# How to check if a namespace is defined in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

Is there some way in PHP to check if a namespace is defined and if it's not define it?

Similar to #IFNDEF DEFINE something #ENDIF but with namespaces.

Comment: What purpose would this serve?  Can you give an example of where you would use this?

Comment: I agree with @TimCooper. You could use `define` and `defined` to check for constant that was set, but it would significantly be more useful to check if class was loaded instead of namespace.

Comment: I'm using Doctrine 2 and I have a class with namespace Entity; then I have another class that extends the first one also with namespace Entity; this is mandatory for Doctrine to map it. But then when it executes the class it's like the namespace is Entity\Entity, so I wanted to detect if the namespace Entity was already declared so I don't declare it again but at the same time if it's not declared, define it.